# Calculated column for differences between two column dates with blank check if blank use another column for difference - Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, modern-experience, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I am trying to create a calculated column which shows the number of days' difference between two columns which have dates in them. I understand that I can get this with the following formula:

```
=DATEDIF([Date 1],[Date 2],"D")
```

which indeed works, as long as there is a date in both columns.

I am looking for formula - if one of the date is blank, then it should use another column date to find difference

My Calculated column would be names as `[daysvacant]`
Days between `[PositionFilleddate]` - `[resigneddate]`

if `[Positionfilleddate]` is blank, then I want `[Today]-[resigneddate]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK([Positionfilleddate]), DATEDIF([resigneddate], Today(), "d"), DATEDIF([resigneddate], [Positionfilleddate], "d"))
```

**References**:

1. [Calculate the difference between two dates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)#calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: Yes, Thanks. It worked

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i did exactly the same, it worked

=IF(ISBLANK([Positionfilleddate]), DATEDIF([resigneddate], Today(), "d"), DATEDIF([resigneddate], [Positionfilleddate], "d"))